# resizing facebook tab according to content

Tags: facebook

I was using this code before head tag to set the size of the canvas on the tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize( {height: 1500} );
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize( {height: 1500} );
}
</script>
```

then before the closing body tag

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : '<<app id here>>', 
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});
</script>
```

This worked fine but lot of hassle getting it just right in different browsers. Found another lot of code on here which was as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
fb_root = document.createElement( 'div' );
fb_root.id = 'fb-root';
try
{
window.document.childNodes[0].appendChild( fb_root );
}
catch( error )
{
window.document.body.appendChild( fb_root );
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId  : '561492603881225', //your app ID
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
});

//FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

var mySetSize = function() {
    var height = getDocHeight();
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: height });
    setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
};
setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style'),
rules = document.createTextNode('body { position: relative; max-width:      520px!important;width: 520px!important; overflow: hidden!important; margin: 0px!important;   }');

style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet)
style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
else style.appendChild(rules);
head.appendChild(style);

</script>
```

Now this worked seemlessly on this first tab https://www.facebook.com/PaycoServices/app_547127248642465 however using it on another like this one https://www.facebook.com/PaycoServices/app_561492603881225 it leaves a white gap at the bottom, any idea why?

Comment: Setting `overflow:hidden` for body might be part of the problem. Why you are using that here anyway, and set the width of body to 520px, although the content is wider than that?

Comment: I removed overflow:hidden and tried again but still the same. To be honest I'm not sure why the width of 520 is in there either, I copied all of this code from another post so I just left it in. It's odd as the first link resizes perfectly (in every browser) and the second using exactly the same code (other than the app id) displays white space at the foot.